# Bug trying to use RewriteRule with a .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I just get into apache config and htaccess files.

I'm coding a very simple portfolio with html, css and js.

I've linked a pdf version of my CV at : .../assets/pdf/Firstname_Lastname_CV.pdf

And I would like to access it with the url .../cv

Here is my .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^assets/pdf/Gael_Fontenelle_CV.pdf$ cv [L]
```

I've tried to resolve this by reading Stackoverflow and others but still ...

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: You are doing it the wrong way around. You want `cv` to be requested by the client, and rewrite this internally to `assets/pdf/Gael_Fontenelle_CV.pdf`

Comment: Oh ... thanks. What a dummy I'm ^^.